# grep fails inside bash script but works on command line

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

The bash file:

```
#!/bin/bash    
grep -l -r "products" Products/
```

gives output

```
: No such file or directory
```

When run directly from the terminal prompt,  `grep -l -r "products" Products/` gives the desired output, which is the list of files containing the word.

I checked using `echo $SHELL` that the shell is indeed `bash` so there should be no difference. What could be the reason? (`Products/` directory contains around 3500 files).

Running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: what does `pwd` say about this?

Comment: Try to use absolute path eks: `/var/Products/`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your script contains a CR at the end of the grep line. Use `dos2unix` to remove it.

Comment: Thanks! That was indeed the problem!