# grep behavior in cli and script differs

Tags: bash, grep

I've got a web server with a bunch of domains that have different name servers and I'm trying to clean up the mess. I'm trying to get a list of the domains and their name servers. I've got this simple script written and it almost works:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in `cat mydomains.txt`
do
    echo $f " " >> mydns.txt
    dig ns $f | grep '^$f' | cut -d $'\t' -f 5 >> mydns.txt
    echo "" >> mydns.txt
done
```

As of right now, all this does is `echo $f " " >> mydns.txt`.

If I take the dig line and substitute what `$f` should be in the command line, I get the expected results. However, I get nothing in my script. I know that the `$f` variable is populated because it echoes `$f` in the previous line. Why doesn't it work in the script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean to grep for '^$f'? It should be '^'"$f", i.e., without the ticks around the variable. It won't be expanded that way.

Answer (score 2):

Single quotes prevent the shell from expanding the variable. You should use double quotes:

```
dig ns "$f" | grep "^$f" | ...
```

Note that I also used double quotes around `$f` in the `dig` call. Quoting your variables is good practice; see [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable) for details.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that it's a Windows-style/Unix-style newline issue. It might help to convert your newlines to \n instead of \r\n.

Have you tried the `dos2unix` suggestion given here: [grep fails inside bash script but works on command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18954067/grep-fails-inside-bash-script-but-works-on-command-line)?

Comment: These files are created in and solely exist in Linux.  There are no Windows newlines.

Comment: Having been created on Linux doesn't necessarily mean the text editor doesn't use CRLF for newlines. Nevertheless, I'm glad you found the solution to your problem. ;)